# UWP extend into title bar - default title bar converting back button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP app, I trying to get the back button into the title bar, which I have done many times in the past. This time, the trouble I'm facing is that the default title bar doesn't seem to be going away, and is hovering over my button so I cannot press it. I tried creating a custom title bar with margins, but that didn't fix it. Here's the extending into title bar...:

```
var coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

...and the custom title bar:

```
var titleBarGrid = new Grid()
{
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    Height = 48,
    Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 150, 0),
};
Window.Current.SetTitleBar(titleBarGrid);
```

These are being set in the App.xaml.cs.

How do I remove/overwrite the default title bar?

Comment: I followed the [Full customization example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/title-bar#full-customization-example) to test. It did not hover the back button, I could press it. See [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I fixed it by moving the `settitlebar(grid)` above `InitializeComponent()`. Martin - If I don't set the color it makes the window not draggable, and then there's nothing to drag except the default left of the minimize button. The grid I made into a titlebar has margins that don't overlap any of my buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the background color of the `titleBarGrid` to `Transparent`. Although this is a fully see-through color, it still acts as a "solid" color in regards to hit testing. If you want to make sure the `Grid` is click through, do not set the `Background` at all.

Also I think that the argument of `SetTitleBar` should be a control that is already a part of the page XAML tree, so you should first add the `Grid` somewhere on the page. The easiest solution is to create in XAML directly.

Finally, if you want to keep the solid background, you can also observe the `Inset` values for title bar which you get from `CoreTitleBar.LayoutMetricsChanged` event. The `SystemOverlayLeftInset` property will tell you how much padding you should add to the left so that the content doesn't overlay the title bar back button.

Finally - I would like to mention that the latest design guidelines discourage the use of back button in the title bar and instead recommend you to implement the back button within your app UI. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation#system-back-behavior-for-backward-compatibilities):

> Previously, UWP apps used AppViewBackButtonVisibility for backwards navigation. The API will continue to be supported for backward compatibility, but we no longer recommend relying on the title bar back button. Instead, your app should draw its own in-app back button.

Back button should be part of you in-app UI, because otherwise it will cause a not-so-nice back button bar to display on top of your app when Sets feature is released in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, see my answer.